# Can newlines be replaces with spaces? (lexer)

Tags: java, token, lexical-analysis

I'm currently in the progress of developing a parser for a subset of Java, and I was wondering;

1. Is there any cases, in which newlines are more than token separators?

   - That is, where they couldn't just be replaced by a space.
2. Should I ignore newlines, in the same way that I ignore white-space?

   - That is, just use them to detect token separation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes all newline characters in Java source code can be replaced by a space or be removed. However, do not remove `\n` (backslash n), because that are the newline characters inside a String literal.

And, yes newlines are for the parser the same as spaces, as long as you are outside String literals. If you are in a String literal, and you would remove a newline, then you would surpress a syntax error. Because it is not allowed in Java to have newline characters in a String literal. So, this is wrong:

```
String str = "first line
same line";
```

So, it depends on the fact if you want to detect syntax errors with your parser or not. Do you only parse valid code or not? That is the question you should ask yourself.

Comment: My string literals do accept '\\n' and not '\n', that is they accept the newline escape, not the newline character.

Comment: You should accept them both. `\\n` is a backslash escaped, followed by `n`. And `\n` is the newline character in escaped form.

Comment: Uhm, I do accept both. I'm writing this parser in C++, and the `\\n`, essentially maps to `\n`, while `\n` maps to ascii line_feed. Due to the fact that C++ reads these as escapes as well. I know you couldn't have known this! I'm using `\\\\n` for a backslash followed by an `n`.

Comment: While you are parsing text from a file, C++ simply reads the bytes. It doesn't parse these escapes at all. If you have in your Java source file `"\n"`, you will read this thing literally byte by byte and get backslash n. So, I think you are thinking one level to deep with these escapes.

Comment: The lexer and parse is written using boost::spirit, I'm having these escapes in my boost regexps for the lexer.

Answer (score 0):

The only situation I can think of where it makes a difference is within String-literals.
If there is a linebreak between two `"`s it would cause a syntax error while a space would not.

Comment: String literals are tokens, which cannot contain newline characters, only the newline escape.

Answer (score 0):

you have to notice that it could come in string \n, and of course if you want to make this replace you have to increase the lines number +1 because you will need it in the next phases of your project.